# jQuery - How to pass an array with ajax to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

```
$.ajax({
            type:"get",
            url:"add/sql_customer.php",
            data:   "?title="+title+
                    "&customerid="+cid+
                    "&action=savecontract",

            success:function(data){
            }
        });
```

I want to post titles as an array.. How can I do that?? I get always undefined or an empty variable.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title[]" placeholder="Titel-1"/>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title[]" placeholder="Titel-2"/>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title[]" placeholder="Titel-3"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the entered titles through an iteration over the input elements with class `title-container`:

```js
$('#btn-submit').click(function(){
    var titles = [];
    
    $('.title-container').each(function(){
     titles.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(titles);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="title-container" placeholder="Title 1"/>
<input type="text" class="title-container" placeholder="Title 2"/>
<input type="text" class="title-container" placeholder="Title 3"/>

<button id="btn-submit">Get titles</button>
```

Comment: And how can i pass it with ajax? :) .. data: titles ?

Comment: `data: { titles: titles, customerid: cid, action: 'savecontract' }` should do it.